# Django performance monitoring on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have a Django app hosted on AWS Lambda (deployed using [Zappa tool](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa)) an using RDS for hosting the Postgres database. The app is having performance issues with some pages loading very slowly but not others, making me think that the issue is with poorly written data interactions.

I remember at work, the devs were using Azure Application Insights which was monitoring apps at a code level. I think the devs had to insert code throughout their apps to get the monitoring, and I think it monitored on a page by page and code line by line basis.

Is there any similar tool on AWS which I could use with my App?

I appreciate there are much simpler ways of solving my problem but I thought an AWS tool would be something neat to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few monitoring and troubleshooting tools that work on the AWS environment.
These tools will help you both dive-in into a specific invocation, thus let you understand what wasted the time, but also understand higher-level insights, such as the average time to a DB call or any 3rd party.

Disclosure: I'm working for Lumigo, which is a company that does exactly that. Here's a screenshot that shows this behavior:[image]